# How to avoid having to explicitly write composite KnownNat constraints?

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, typeclass

I have a typeclass, which imposes a `KnownNat` constraint:

```
class KnownNat (Card a) => HasFin a where
  type Card a :: Nat
  ...
```

And, I have instances of this class for several basic "building block" types:

```
instance HasFin () where
  type Card () = 1
  ...

instance HasFin Bool where
  type Card Bool = 2
  ...
```

I plan to build many "composite" types out of these building block types, using sums and products. Currently, I'm having to explicitly write a composite `KnownNat` constraint, when I instance `HasFin` for one of these composite types:

```
instance (HasFin a, HasFin b, KnownNat (Card a + Card b)) => HasFin (Either a b) where
  type Card (Either a b) = Card a + Card b
  ...
```

I would really like to *not* have to write: `KnownNat (Card a + Card b)`, in the code above.

**Is there any type checker plug-in, which is capable of automatically extrapolating from `(HasFin a, HasFin b) =>` to `(KnownNat (Card a + Card b)) =>` ?**

Failing that, can I write an entailment, which provides the same extrapolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is such a plugin! [ghc-typelits-knownnat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-knownnat)

Example usage:

```
-- Install ghc-typelits-knownnat via your favorite build tool like any other package
-- then only this line needs to be added to enable the plugin
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.KnownNat.Solver #-}

-- Nothing special to be done otherwise, type-level programming as usual.
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Card where

import GHC.TypeLits

class KnownNat (Card a) => HasFin a where
  type Card a :: Nat

instance HasFin () where
  type Card () = 1

instance (HasFin a, HasFin b) => HasFin (Either a b) where
  type Card (Either a b) = Card a + Card b
```

---

Here's another technique without plugins, using the [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint-Nat.html) library. It defines GADT to capture constraints and entailment as value-level dictionaries, and provides a few axioms, including the `(KnownNat a, KnownNat b) :- KnownNat (a + b)` entailment.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Card where

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Nat
import GHC.TypeLits

class HasFin a where
  type Card a :: Nat
  card :: Dict (KnownNat (Card a))

instance HasFin () where
  type Card () = 1
  card = Dict

instance (HasFin a, HasFin b) => HasFin (Either a b) where
  type Card (Either a b) = Card a + Card b
  card =
    case (card @a, card @b, plusNat @(Card a) @(Card b)) of
      (Dict, Dict, Sub Dict) -> Dict
```

Comment: Btw, do you have an example for this plugin usage? Like, some minimal project with steps to build and use? And explanation, if possible...

Comment: I added some example code (and an alternative solution). There's not much to do, install the plugin like any other package, enable some command line options and that's it.